# Nonce Too Low, try incrementing nonce | Not able to send TRX

Tags: nonce

Can someone tell me how to correct a Nonce Too Low issue?

I'm trying to send an ERC 20 TRX tokens that I have stored on my nano s ETC wallet and I'm not able to due to this low nonce.

FYI I have no idea what this Low Nonce means.  Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean ETH wallet, rather than ETC..?

Comment: No.  New to the game I may have done this wrong initially.  

I originally sent TRX to my ETC wallet address.   Which does, in fact, reflect the balance sent. 

After realizing the difference between ETC and ETH I sent my second batch of TRX to my ETH nano S wallet. 

I would like to have all my TRX in the same wallet.  However, when ever I try to send them from my ETC to my ETH I receive an error that nonce is to low.

I did do a test and I was able to send a few TRX from my ETH to my ETC address.  So i'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: If anyone can provide any suggestion on how to get my TRX off from my ETC wallet that would be much appreciated.

I'm starting to feel like they're stuck there... I don't have the knowledge to get them off and I've searched for hours on end yet cannot find a solution.

Comment: What wallet are you using for your ETC address?

Comment: I was finally able to resolve the problem.  I had to select the ETC m/44'/60'/160720'/0' option for my HD derivation path.  While logging in to my ETH wallet.  

Doing so allow me to successfully transfer my TRX from my ETC wallet to my ETH.